# RabbitMQ message size problems

Tags: rabbitmq, message-queue, messagebroker, cowboy

We have been using RabbitMQ as a broker. It sits between our client  written in Go with NGINX and the API server. We have used it successfully until now. The message size that we are using has increased to ~20mb. Sending this large message consistently causes the following error:

> =ERROR REPORT==== 20-Oct-2018::11:17:59 === Error in process <0.21106.0> on node 'rabbit@pc11213' with exit value:
>   {[{reason,{badmatch,{more,<<8001224
>   bytes>>,{http_req,#Port<0.99287>,ranch_tcp,keepalive,<0.21106.0>,<<4
>   bytes>>,'HTTP/1.1',{{127,0,0,1},58904},<<9
>   bytes>>,undefined,15672,<<39 bytes>>,undefined,<<0
>   bytes>>,[],[{exchange,<<12 bytes>>},{vhost,<<3 bytes>>}],[{<<4
>   bytes>>,<<15 bytes>>},{<<10 bytes>>,<<18 bytes>>},{<<14 bytes>>,<<8
>   bytes>>},{<<13 bytes>>,<<26 bytes>>},{<<12 bytes>>,<<16 bytes>>},{<<15
>   bytes>>,<<4 bytes>>}],[{<<14 bytes>>,20432940},{<<17 bytes>>,[<<8
>   bytes>>]},{<<6 bytes>>,undefined},{<<12 bytes>>,{<<11 bytes>>,<<4
>   bytes>>,[]}},{<<17 bytes>>,undefined},{<<13 bytes>>,undefined},{<<19 
>   bytes>>,undefined...

- watching network traffic with wireshark shows, that the server sends
  a 500 reply in the middle of the TCP transfer stream sent by the
  client, which indicates that the server can not cope with the
  incoming data

We are using the HTTP management endpoint and plugins:

```
=INFO REPORT==== 19-Oct-2018::14:28:44 === Server startup complete; 6 plugins started.
  * rabbitmq_management
  * rabbitmq_web_dispatch
  * rabbitmq_management_agent
  * cowboy
  * cowlib
  * amqp_client
```

We tried changing the rabbitMQ/ cowboy server config to no avail e.g.

```
[{rabbitmq_management,
   [{listener, [{port,        15672},
                {cowboy_opts, [{ max_request_line_length, 16000 },{max_keepalive, 1000}]}
               ]}
   ]
}].
```

- default max_request_line_length was 8000 -> increased to 160000
  *how can I be sure that these parameters are actually applied ?*
- also changing req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data")
  did not help in go client

So our feeling is we either need to move away from rabbitMQ or use some other protocol with a different plugin.

We feel rabbitMQ should not be limited on message size. We would rather not try to reference a payload in the message. Any suggestions as to how we can increase the tolerated message size?

**Edit:**
We tried further modifications to cowboy settings:

```
{rabbitmq_management,
     [{cors_allow_origins,[]},
      {cors_max_age,1800},
      {http_log_dir,none},
      {listener,
          [{port,15672},
           {cowboy_opts,
               [{compress,true},
                {max_request_line_length,160000},
                {max_keepalive,1000},
                {idle_timeout,120000},
                {inactivity_timeout,120000},
                {request_timeout,120000}]}]},
      {load_definitions,none},
      {management_db_cache_multiplier,5},
      {process_stats_gc_timeout,300000},
      {stats_event_max_backlog,250}]},
```

Which produced the same error:

> 2018/10/24 16:31:06 Size of file listing:20431558 2018/10/24 16:31:06
>   Extracted pid:20.# 2018/10/24 16:31:07 Post
>   http://derived:#@localhost:#/api/exchanges/%2F/derived-exchange/publish:
>   net/http: HTTP/1.x transport connection broken: write tcp
>   127.#->127.#: write: connection reset by peer

Answer (score 1):

it looks error is misleading. ideally rabbitmq shouldn't limit on message size. But HTTP API may have restrictions.

RabbitMQ (in fact any queueing solution) is not ideal for exchanging large size messages. Instead store large size message in a Object storage (AWS s3) and publish stored objects meta data to queue.

Other options ...

1. Try using AMQP to exchange large size messages with RabbitMQ.
2. Try increasing cowboy_opts --> request_timeout (milli seconds).

   ```
          {cowboy_opts, [{compress, true},
                         %% 120 seconds
                         {idle_timeout,      120000},
                         {inactivity_timeout,120000},
                         {request_timeout,   120000}]}
         ]}
   ```